# Do you I have to explicitly set cache=true for the bean component uri option for a singleton?

Tags: apache-camel

With Spring ApplicationContextRegistry, I understand that in the bean definition, scope is singleton by default. So, in the example below, the scope property is redundant.

```
<bean id="heartbeatHandler" class="org.cybersecurity.ewf.HeartbeatHandler" scope="singleton"/>
```

But in the 'to uri' below, I want to confirm whether we need to explicitly set cache=true?

```
<to uri="bean:heartBeatHandler?method=respondToHeartBeat&cache=true"/>
```

Why do we need to set at 2 places?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to set either `scope="singleton"` or `cache=true` to use singleton beans. It's default.

The cache just caches the registry lookup.

Comment: Thank you very much Petter for the clarification.